# Cannot Start A Certain Node Manager After Decommissioning Some Nodes

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hadoop-yarn

I have a cluster with 1 namenode and 6 datanodes. After decommissioning 3 of the datanodes. Our YARN service is always bad health. And seems like the nodemanager on one of the datanodes never gets started successfully. Then I tried to restart the nodemanager on that box. And here are the logs.

```
2014-08-01 11:19:08,217 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system shutdown complete.
2014-08-01 11:19:08,217 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager ,Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: Disallowed NodeManager from  box708.datafireball.com, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(NodeManager.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:398)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager ,Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: Disallowed NodeManager from  box708.datafireball.com, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.registerWithRM(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:179)
    ... 6 more
```

I googled around this error but cannot find the solution, any guidance from anyone?

Answer (score 2):

`Message from ResourceManager: Disallowed NodeManager`

This message means that either your NodeManager isn't in the allowed list of nodemanagers or it's in the list of excluded.

Check configuration of your resourcemanager for the following properties:

`yarn.resourcemanager.nodes.include-path`

`yarn.resourcemanager.nodes.exclude-path`

Answer (score 0):

buryat is correct. I had this same problem and the fix was to add all the nodes to the include list. But I would like to add this note to anyone running across this issue.

Make sure and add EXACTLY the hostname that yarn is complaining about. In your example ResourceManager: Disallowed NodeManager from  **box708.datafireball.com**

For my case I was adding a node named "gpu-0-5". The "gpu-0-5" hostname was in my yarn.include file and yarn kept complaining. I noticed it said "gpu-0-5.local" (even though gpu-0-5 routes to the same machine). Once I added gpu-0-5.local to my yarn.include list it started working.

I'm not sure how to change the configuration in yarn to only require "gpu-0-5".